# Symfony 3 2 entities one form

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to figure it out how to use two entities in a single form.
I have User entity and Profile entity. I've created a RegisterType class that holds the fields for the User Entity and after that i added a one-to-one mapping between User and Profile. Now in my RegisterType i would like to have fields related to the ProfileEntity like phone, address. I tried creating an instance of ProfileType which is the form builder class for the Profile entity and then create an instance of it inside the RegisterType like this

```
->add('profile', ProfileType::class, [])
```

In my registerAction method after form submit i added the following line to add the relation and save the data for the fields related to the Profile entity.

```
$user->setProfile($form['profile']->getData()->setUser($user));
```

I did it like that because if i wouldn't have the above line it wouldn't save the mapping between user and profile. What is approach that i should use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bogdan, you're right, it's not very clean.

You don't need to set profile by yourself in registerAction because it should be done by the setter in user entity.

I am almost certain that your setter looks like this :

```
Class User
{
    setProfile($profile) {
        $this->profile = $profile;
    }
}
```

But it must be like this :

```
Class User
{
    setProfile($profile) {
        $this->profile = $profile;
        $profile->setUser($this);
    }
}
```

This is the same as what you did but in the setter :)

Comment: yeap that would be a better way =D